# How to find a pattern using sed?

Tags: unix, command-line, sed

How can I combine multiple filters using `sed`?

Here's my data set

```
sex,city,age
male,london,32
male,manchester,32
male,oxford,64
female,oxford,23
female,london,33
male,oxford,45
```

I want to identify all lines which contain MALE **AND** OXFORD. Here's my approach:

```
sed -n '/male/,/oxford/p' file
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can associate a block with the first check and put the second in there. For example:

```
sed -n '/male/ { /oxford/ p; }' file
```

Or invert the check and action:

```
sed '/male/!d; /oxford/!d' file
```

However, since (as @Jotne points out) lines that contain `female` also contain `male` and you probably don't want to match them, the patterns should at least be amended to contain word boundaries:

```
sed -n '/\<male\>/ { /\<oxford\>/ p; }' file
sed '/\<male\>/!d; /\<oxford\>/!d' file
```

But since that looks like comma-separated data and the check is probably not meant to test whether someone went to `male` university, it would probably be best to use a stricter check with awk:

```
awk -F, '$1 == "male" && $2 == "oxford"' file
```

This checks not only if a line contains `male` and `oxford` but also if they are in the appropriate fields. The same can be achieved, somewhat less prettily, with sed by using

```
sed '/^male,oxford,/!d' file
```

Comment: This hits on  `female` too.

Comment: OP does not say field 1 and field 2 does contain the word, just like to get lines with `MALE AND OXFORD`, but for his data set it should be ok.

Comment: I am inferring things about the structure of the data, that's true, but if my inference is correct, testing for the fields is a much saner test in my view.

Comment: `sed '/^male,oxford,/!d' file` works for me. why does it not work for a csv file if the data set looks like that `sex,city,agemale,london,32
male,manchester,32
male,oxford,64
female,oxford,23
female,london,33
male,oxford,45`

Comment: It should (assuming the linebreaks are where I expect them). What is the output you get?

Comment: @cosmin This is because it test for `^male`, that is `male` in start of the line

Comment: Ahhh .... **it's case sensitive** - im my data set the city names start with a capital letter. I think I have have to lowercase my data. thanks everybody!!!!!

Comment: Put the `I` flag on the tests: `sed '/^male,oxford,/I!d' file`. This causes (GNU) sed to match case-insensitively.

Comment: You're using MacOS X, aren't you?

Comment: MacOS X comes with BSD sed, which becomes painful for anything beyond the most basic things. My suggestion is to use `awk -F, 'tolower($1) == "male" && tolower($2) == "oxford"' file`.

Comment: here's another approach: 1 step: lowercase the whole dataset 2. step: parse the data set `awk '{ print tolower($0) }' file | awk -F, '$1 == "male" && $2 == "oxford"'`

Comment: If it isn't a problem that the output is converted to lower case, that also works, yes.

Answer (score 1):

A single `sed` command command can be used to solve this. Let's look at two variations of using `sed`:

```
$ sed -e 's/^\(male,oxford,.*\)$/\1/;t;d' file
male,oxford,64
male,oxford,45
$ sed -e 's/^male,oxford,\(.*\)$/\1/;t;d' file
64
45
```

Both have the essentially the same `regex`:

```
^male,oxford,.*$
```

The interesting features are the capture group placement (either the whole line or just the age portion) and the use of `;t;d` to discard non matching lines.

By doing it this way, we can avoid the requirement of using `awk` or `grep` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk -F, '/\<male\>/ && /\<oxford\>/' file
male,oxford,64
male,oxford,45
```

It uses the word anchor to prevent hit on female.